# what is the differences between class and classifier in UML

Tags: class, uml, specifications

When i read through `UML specification` there is two words i am not sure if both are the same or not 
those words are:

class and classifier

What is the differences between

- class and classifier?

Answer (score 5):

The term *classifier* is more general than *class*.  A classifier can include an interface or even a use case.

In practice, I've only run across the term *classifier* in certain situations, notably when using a tool such as MagicDraw.

You can read more here: [What do you mean by classifiers in UML?](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_do_you_mean_by_classifiers_in_unified_modeling_language)